# Error: Can't find /api/v1/users/signup but Postman displays the data of the route

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm facing a weird error in /signup and /login routes

Vscode keeps showing me "Error: Can't find /api/v1/users/signup on the server :( !"

on the other hand, Postman's status is "success" and everything is running ok and as expected.

the same thing happens for /login

here are the related codes :

app.js:

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);

usersRoute.js:

```
router.post("/signup", authController.signup);
router.post("/login", authController.login);
```

the headers of signup and login:

```
exports.signup = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {}
exports.login = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {}
```

the piece of code where I'm receiving the error is here:
note: I added console.log to make sure where the error occurs and I've found that it occurs just after making a POST request from Postman, the first thing was printed in my console is `console.log("INSIDE CATCHASYNC 2");`

```
const catchAsync = (asyncFunction) => {  
  console.log("INSIDE CATCHASYNC 1");
  
  return (request, response, next) => {
    console.log("INSIDE CATCHASYNC 2");
    asyncFunction(request, response, next).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.stack);
      
      console.log("INSIDE CATCHASYNC 3");
      next(error);
    });
  };
};

exports.login = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {
  console.log("++++++1+++++++");
  
  const { email, password } = request.body;

  // 1- checking email and pawword :
  if (!email || !password)
    return next(new AppError(400, "Please provide your email and password to login !"));

  // 2- checking if the user is exists and the entered data match with db data or not :
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }) // we're using findOne not ById because in the situation we're not selecting a user by its id but with user's email .
    .select("+password"); 

  // 3- okay? send the token to the user:
  if (!user || !(await user.comparePassword(password, user.password)))
    return next(new AppError(401, "Incorrect email or password !"));
  
    console.log("++++++2+++++++");
  const token = signature(user._id);
  console.log("++++++12+++++++");
  response.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    token
  });
  console.log("above next() in login");

  next();
});
```

here is a screenshot of the console:

[image]

Comment: i cannot understand where you are receiving the error; you're saying that in postman performing the request POST /api/v1/users/signup, the endpoint is triggered properly right? can you show the code where you're receiving the error, or update your explanation?

Comment: @mikrowdev thanks for replying, I've edited my question and added more details and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside this code

```js
exports.login = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {
  console.log("++++++1+++++++");
  
  const { email, password } = request.body;

  // 1- checking email and pawword :
  if (!email || !password)
    return next(new AppError(400, "Please provide your email and password to login !"));

  // 2- checking if the user is exists and the entered data match with db data or not :
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }) // we're using findOne not ById because in the situation we're not selecting a user by its id but with user's email .
    .select("+password"); 

  // 3- okay? send the token to the user:
  if (!user || !(await user.comparePassword(password, user.password)))
    return next(new AppError(401, "Incorrect email or password !"));
  
    console.log("++++++2+++++++");
  const token = signature(user._id);
  console.log("++++++12+++++++");
  response.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    token
  });
  console.log("above next() in login");

  next();
});
```

You should not perform the call at the final `next()` as, next is supposed to be used to pass to the next middleware, but as i can see you are performing a response return with

```
response.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    token
  });
```

so you don't expect to have a next middleware, anyway, even if you wanted to execute another middleware you should pass to it the `request`, `response` objects, as like this `next(request,response,next)` to ensure that the next middleware has access to the previous request state.

If i understood bad, please update your question and i'll improve my answer

Comment: the problem was sloved thank you very much ! I thought that next() is a must at the end of any middleware so I kept writing it, but this leads to another question if you may allow me to ask, why this problem happened to me in these two routes only ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've read your answer many times  to understand why I faced the error. Thank you for helping me